# Get regions from a file that are part of regions in other file (Without loops)

Tags: perl, matlab, sed, awk

I have two files:

regions.txt: First column is the chromosome name, second and third are start and end position.

```
1  100  200
1  400  600
2  600  700
```

coverage.txt: First column is chromosome name, again second and third are start and end positions, and last column is the score.

```
1 100 101  5
1 101 102  7 
1 103 105  8
2 600 601  10
2 601 602  15
```

This file is very huge it is about 15GB with about 300 million lines.

I basically want to get the mean of all scores in coverage.txt that are in each region in regions.txt.

In other words, start at the first line in regions.txt, if there is a line in coverage.txt which has the same chromosome, start-coverage is >= start-region, and end-coverage is <= end-region, then save its score to a new array. After finish searching in all coverages.txt print the region chromosome, start, end, and the mean of all scores that have been found.

Expected output:

```
1  100 200 14.6   which is (5+7+8)/3
1  400 600 0      no match at coverages.txt
2  600 700 12.5   which is (10+15)/2
```

I built the following MATLAB script which take very long time since I have to loop over coverage.txt many time. I don't know how to make a fast awk similar script.

My matlab script

```
fc = fopen('coverage.txt', 'r');
ft = fopen('regions.txt', 'r');
fw = fopen('out.txt', 'w');

while feof(ft) == 0

linet = fgetl(ft);
scant = textscan(linet, '%d%d%d');
tchr = scant{1};
tx = scant{2};
ty = scant{3};
coverages = [];

    frewind(fc);
    while feof(fc) == 0

    linec = fgetl(fc);
    scanc = textscan(linec, '%d%d%d%d');
    cchr = scanc{1};
    cx = scanc{2};
    cy = scanc{3};
    cov = scanc{4};


        if (cchr == tchr) && (cx >= tx) && (cy <= ty)

            coverages = cat(2, coverages, cov);

        end

    end

    covmed = median(coverages);
    fprintf(fw, '%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n', tchr, tx, ty, covmed);

end
```

Any suggestions to make an alternative using AWK, Perl, or , ... etc  I will aslo be pleased if someone can teach me how to get rid of all loops in my matlab script.

Thanks

Comment: How many lines are in region.txt? Are the start and end positions disjoint (non-overlapping except for start/end)?

Comment: Regions.txt is just 4500 lines. Regions at regions.txt are all non overlapping with each other.

Comment: Is your data files tab separated or fixed width?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a Perl solution. I use hashes (aka dictionaries) to access the various ranges via the chromosome, thus reducing the number of loop iterations.

This is potentially efficient, as I don't do a full loop over `regions.txt` on every input line. Efficiency could perhaps be increased further when multithreading is used.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my ($rangefile) = @ARGV;
open my $rFH, '<', $rangefile    or die "Can't open $rangefile";

# construct the ranges. The chromosome is used as range key.
my %ranges;
while (<$rFH>) {
    chomp;
    my @field = split /\s+/;
    push @{$ranges{$field[0]}}, [@field[1,2], 0, 0];
}
close $rFH;

# iterate over all the input
while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($chrom, $lower, $upper, $value) = split /\s+/, $line;
    # only loop over ranges with matching chromosome
    foreach my $range (@{$ranges{$chrom}}) {
        if ($$range[0] <= $lower and $upper <= $$range[1]) {
            $$range[2]++;
            $$range[3] += $value;
            last; # break out of foreach early because ranges don't overlap
        }
    }
}

# create the report
foreach my $chrom (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %ranges) {
    foreach my $range (@{$ranges{$chrom}}) {
        my $value = $$range[2] ? $$range[3]/$$range[2] : 0;
        printf "%d %d %d %.1f\n", $chrom, @$range[0,1], $value;
    }
}
```

Example invocation:

```
$ perl script.pl regions.txt <coverage.txt >output.txt
```

Output on the example input:

```
1 100 200 6.7
1 400 600 0.0
2 600 700 12.5
```

(because (5+7+8)/3 = 6.66…)

Comment: This looks a nice solution to me. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, I would load the files into R and calculate it, but given that one of them is so huge, this would become a problem. Here are some thoughts that might help you solving it.

1. Consider splitting `coverage.txt` by chromosomes. This would make the calculations less demanding.
2. Instead of looping over `coverage.txt`, you first read the `regions.txt` full into memory (I assume it is *much* smaller). For each region, you keep a score and a number.
3. Process `coverage.txt` line by line. For each line, you determine the chromosome and the region that this particular stretch belongs to. This will require some footwork, but if `regions.txt` is not too large, it might be more efficient. Add the score to the score of the region and increment number by one.

An alternative, most efficient way requires both files to be sorted first by chromosome, then by position.

1. Take a line from `regions.txt`. Record the chromosome and positions. If there is a line remaining from previous loop, go to 3.; otherwise go to 2.
2. Take a line from `coverage.txt`.
3. Check whether it is within the current region.

   - yes: add the score to the region, increment number. Move to 2.
   - no: divide score by number, write the current region to output, go to 1.

This last method requires some fine tuning, but will be most efficient -- it requires to go through each file only once and does not require to store almost anything in the memory.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `join` and `awk`. Run like:

```
join regions.txt coverage.txt | awk -f script.awk - regions.txt
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
FNR==NR && $4>=$2 && $5<=$3 { 
    sum[$1 FS $2 FS $3]+=$6
    cnt[$1 FS $2 FS $3]++
    next
}

{
    if ($1 FS $2 FS $3 in sum) {
        printf "%s  %.1f\n", $0, sum[$1 FS $2 FS $3]/cnt[$1 FS $2 FS $3]
    }
    else if (NF == 3) {
        print $0 "  0"
    }
}
```

Results:

```
1  100  200  6.7
1  400  600  0
2  600  700  12.5
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
join regions.txt coverage.txt | awk 'FNR==NR && $4>=$2 && $5<=$3 { sum[$1 FS $2 FS $3]+=$6; cnt[$1 FS $2 FS $3]++; next } { if ($1 FS $2 FS $3 in sum) printf "%s  %.1f\n", $0, sum[$1 FS $2 FS $3]/cnt[$1 FS $2 FS $3]; else if (NF == 3) print $0 "  0" }' - regions.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple MATLAB way to bin your coverage into regions:

```
% extract the regions extents
bins = regions(:,2:3)';
bins = bins(:);

% extract the coverage - only the start is needed
covs = coverage(:,2);

% use histc to place the coverage start into proper regions
% this line counts how many coverages there are in a region
% and assigns them proper region ids.
[h, i]= histc(covs(:), bins(:));

% sum the scores into correct regions (second output of histc gives this)
total = accumarray(i, coverage(:,4), [numel(bins),1]);

% average the score in regions (first output of histc is useful)
avg = total./h;

% remove every second entry - our regions are defined by start/end
avg = avg(1:2:end);
```

Now this works assuming that the regions are non-overlapping, but I guess that is the case. Also, every entry in the `coverage` file has to fall into some region.

Also, it is trivial to 'block' this approach over coverages, if you want to avoid reading in the whole file. You only need the `bins`, your regions file, which presumably is small. You can process the coverages in blocks, incrementally add to `total` and compute the average in the end.